# Firebase (FCM) - Users stop receiving notifications on subscribed topic

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase to send notifications to users who installed my app.
After a while some (not many) of them stop receiving notifications although they didn't unsubscribed.

I have a class that suppose to refresh then token, so I have no idea what can cause that.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    }

}
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Are the refreshed tokens subscribed automatically? (Basing from the code snippet you have, it does not)

Comment: Oh... I think you're right. Where do you think is the right place to do it? Just after getting the new token?

Comment: You should do it both in the `onCreate()` of your initial Activity and inside your `onTokenRefresh()`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the code snippet below:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    if(null != refreshedToken) {
     FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the service in your manifest, like so?

```
<service android:name="MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Yes, except that the attribute android:exported="false" is missing. Does it matter? the users do get the messages, just a few of them stops getting them after a while (re-installing solved them the problem). thanks

Comment: Hmm sounds like a refresh token issue. The exported="false" shouldn't matter.